# Why does Ruby's fnmatch not match file in subdirs with FNM_PATHNAME?

Tags: ruby, gitlab, fnmatch

[Gitlab CI uses this code for globs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/build/rules/rule/clause/changes.rb#L21):

```
File.fnmatch?(glob, path, File::FNM_PATHNAME | File::FNM_DOTMATCH | File::FNM_EXTGLOB)
```

If I want to match all files and folders under a directory I think you have to do this:

```
foo/*
foo/**/*
```

That sucks. I thought this would work:

```
foo/**
```

But it only works without `FNM_PATHNAME`. The Ruby docs for this are extremely bad. What exactly is going on here? Is there a single pattern that will match `foo/a` *and* `foo/a/b`?

Comment: Looks like `foo/**` is in fnmatch broken, and perhaps that's why its not being used across GitLab examples

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out that `foo/**/*` does match `foo/a` *only if you have `FNM_PATHNAME`*.